# .Net Windows Service Throws EventType clr20r3 system.data.sqlclient.sql error

Tags: c#, sql, windows-services, sqlclient

I have a .Net/c# 2.0 windows service.  The entry point is wrapped in a try catch block that notifies me of problems and allows the service to continue operating normally yet when I look at the server's application event log I see a number of "EventType clr20r3" errors that are causing the service to die unexpectedly.  The catch block has a "catch (Exception ex)" and does not rethrow the exception.

Each sql commands is of the type "CommandType.StoredProcedure" and are executed with SqlDataReader's.  These sproc calls function correctly 99% of time and have all been thoroughly unit tested, profiled, and QA'd.  I additionally wrapped these calls in try catch blocks just to be sure and am still experiencing these unhandled exceptions.

This only in our production environment and cannot be duplicated in our dev or staging environments (even under heavy load).

**Why would my error handling not catch this particular error?  Is there anyway to capture more detail as to the root cause of the problem?**

Here is an example of the event log:

> ```
> EventType clr20r3, P1 RDC.OrderProcessorService, 
> P2 1.0.0.0, 
> P3 4ae6a0d0, 
> P4 system.data, 
> P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889deaf, 
> P7 2490, 
> P8 2c, 
> P9 system.data.sqlclient.sql, 
> P10 NIL.
> ```

Additionally

> ```
> The Order Processor service terminated unexpectedly.  
> It has done this 1 time(s).  
> The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: 
> Restart the service.
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other exceptions being logged in the EventLog?

Comment: Have you tried adding an AppDomain.UnhandledException event handler?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Pretty much the problem is you have an unhandled SQL exception somewhere in your code.

Comment: Positive.  I just see pairs of messages indicating the above error and a messages indicating the service has been restarted.

Comment: Serapth...I have not.  I will give that a try.  That might be part of the answer.  Are you indicating system.data.sqlclient.sql might spin up its own appdomain?

Comment: I see that you mention placing the calls into a try catch block... Is this an implementation of the following, http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2010/02/solved-error-1053-eventtype-clr20r3.html    ?

Comment: KSimons.  Yes I have done something very similar.

Comment: Not necessarily, but without seeing your code or the libraries you are using, there is no way to know if the exception is occuring in a different thread, in a 3rd party library, etc...  By wiring an AppDomain.UnhandledException handler, you should at least by able to log the exception details and figure out where your problem point is.  Just cast the EventArg to ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message and you should at least have a better idea where your unhandled exception is.

Comment: Check out, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793966.aspx, it's quite a read about unhandled exceptions (including what each part of the event log entry means (like P4 = "the faulting module")). I'm with Serapth on this.

Comment: @Serapth - you are right.  There was a library that was an async call to a db transaction that had no error handling.  If you want to post an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer from comments. Glad to have helped. :)

> Have you tried adding an
>   AppDomain.UnhandledException event
>   handler?
>   msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/…
>   Pretty much the problem is you have an
>   unhandled SQL exception somewhere in
>   your code.
>
> Not necessarily, but without seeing
>   your code or the libraries you are
>   using, there is no way to know if the
>   exception is occuring in a different
>   thread, in a 3rd party library, etc...
>   By wiring an
>   AppDomain.UnhandledException handler,
>   you should at least by able to log the
>   exception details and figure out where
>   your problem point is. Just cast the
>   EventArg to
>   ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message
>   and you should at least have a better
>   idea where your unhandled exception
>   is.

Answer (score 1):

This error is most likely happening on a thread other than your entry point.

You need to somehow define exception handling for your background threads as well.

If you are using WCF to wrap your service, you have the ability to define how faults and other exceptions are handled.  Is this how you're hosting your service?

**EDIT:** If you aren't spawning anything asynchronously, and it's not a WCF/etc app, try handling AppDomain.UnhandledException and logging the detailed error there.

Comment: He said it's a Windows service, not a Web (or other communicative) service.

Comment: I have wrapped all sql calls in try catches as well.  I do not spin up any threads from within these calls nor do I make any other kind of asynchronous calls.  And as Adam mentioned this is a Windows Service.

Comment: Just because it's a windows service doesn't mean that you're not using Remoting or WCF -- you can easily host that stuff inside a Windows service.

Comment: I made the distinction because there wasn't any reason to *think* it's a WCF service. Hoofbeats and zebras and all.